# Sound latency in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, flash-cs5

I am triggering short sounds dynamically from the library for a game (Specifically Air for Android). When the user clicks a button the sound can take up to 600ms to actually play.
I have set it for any silence before the actual sound by calling the sound like so:

```
private var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
private var buttonClickSound:Sound = new button_click();

public function buttonDownClick() {
    channel = buttonClickSound.play(63);
}
```

Still getting a ridiculous amount of latency.

Things I have tried:
converting MP3 to wav
placing Sound Clip in the timeline
calling Sound Clip from urlLoader

All return the same results. I know there are threads here that talk about this but none have offered a real solution that I can find. Is there no way to cache the sound or store it in a buffer?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Any chance you have any solutions? You helped me out with the video lag, I know you have something up your sleeve for this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important update**

The flash CS5 AIR for android functionality was never out of beta. And sadly as adobe is famous for, the functionality has been discontinued for flash CS5 so that the full working/updated version will become a selling feature for CS6 or CS5.5. I have many, many feelings about this as a customer who has spent literally MANY THOUSANDS of dollars on adobe products but I'll keep this about information and not my <strike>burning rage towards adobe</strike> feelings. For proof of this see:

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashpro_extensionforair/

So it is most likely that this is one of many bugs left unfixed in AIR for android in CS5. This is not a surprise, as when I bought CS4 master collection which promised AIR 1.5, even AIR 1.5 was left broken and all bug fixes were rolled into 2.0, which was only available for CS5. One of the biggest bugs they never fixed in CS4 AIR 1.5 was a major, crippling bug in webkit which nearly rendered any use of webkit in AIR non-functional. In fact when I worked for Webkinz.com, a major project was completely thrown out the window and I was actually ridiculed for proposing using AIR, touting all it's amazingness and then left looking like an idiot in front of all my peers when these bugs appeared. Literally I'm not kidding the head of my 180+ developer division centered me out in a meeting around a gigantic table with every major player in that company.

Anyway perhaps my update did bleed into somewhat of a rant but it's good information I think and a good lesson to be learned, which is always assume the worst with Adobe products. Fortunately, as mentioned in my answer, it's not a dead end and there are ways around their "business model."

**Original Answer**

It's a bug in AIR for Android:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/753977

That post is dated, but I've seen several more around the same time frame and enough that I'd call it a fact. Have you updated flash CS5? ( Go to Help->Updates). To be honest I don't even know if they have patched/addressed this bug yet but your best bet of finding out is to grab the very latest Flex SDK and try manually packaging your SWF into an APK using it. Instructions:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac25d3d8c712b2d86751e-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac25d3d8c712b2d86751e-7ffb

More detailed/tutorial-like instructions:

http://thulasiramsoft.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/build-apps-for-android-using-as3-without-a-device-using-flex-air/

If this is a bug this is where you're going to see the fix appear first. Try packaging your SWF into an APK manually using the above methods and ensure you've updated the AIR for android on the device to AIR 2.6 (latest, just go to the market to update). This will either fix the problem or eliminate it as a possibility both on the compiler and runtime side.

Comment: To be honest I have a hard time believing myself that this is indeed still a bug/issue, but I've found evidence suggesting that at least at one time, it was. Perhaps you're still using the air for android plugin from the beta tests. Running the IDE update will determine this, or opening Adobe Extension Manager (which will check for plugin updates).

Comment: Nevermind, I am now nearly positive it is a bug in the flash/compile side. See my updated answer. Typical adobe.

Comment: I had a feeling that these were the solutions that would be presented, considering Adobe's track record and the perfect score I have been having with the Air for Android development already(too good to be true). I have tried packaging it manually through the adobeAIRSDK instead of the flash IDE, still same results. I will try flex next but I doubt I will get different results. That's a very interesting story though, I can't imagine going through that, especially since I like to sit in my own little corner at work with headphones on and not be expected to make decisions like that.

Comment: I am also up-to-date with the latest version  of flash.

Comment: lol it wasn't fun and it pretty much cost me my credibility there. But oh well, ganz (webkinz) is honestly, a hole. It's pretty much where people start out at the (absolute) bottom and leave after a few months to better things. Anyway try the flex SDK and try the nightly builds (Hero). This is where active development is going on and the whole focus of the hero builds is mobile development so they're your best chance.

Comment: Another post I've found states that their audio delays in AIR for android were caused by the fact that basically the entire application was so process intensive that the sounds were delayed from plain old lag. Source: http://flixel.org/forums/index.php?topic=2924.0;prev_next=prev. This may be relevant given the fact that in the past you had laggy/slow performance issues.

Comment: My initial thought on this issue was lag but I am still holding out hope that it might be a compiler error since I have not yet tried to build the apk with flex. My last ditch effort was a byteArray of the audio file but still same results. Hopefully tonight I get a chance to try the flex build. This is a huge inconvenience if I have to purchase cs5.5 in order to get sound to sync correctly. Let alone this being a major drawback to writing robust Android games on the Air platform.

Answer (score 0):

Sound latency is a bug in Flash exporting to AIR.

Easy way around is to make some background music playing, then sound device doesn't go to sleep. If you don't want music you can make some silent sound playing forever. This solves the problem with sound delay for other short sounds.

```
[Embed(source="sfx.mp3")]
const snd_sfx:Class;

const sfx:Sound = new snd_sfx();

const SilentSoundTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);

function playSoundSilentlyEndlessly(evt:Event = null):void
{
    sfx.play(0, 1000, SilentSoundTransform).addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playSoundSilentlyEndlessly, false, 0, true); // plays the sound with volume 0 endlessly
}

playSoundSilentlyEndlessly();
```